# simple Find, replace and delete macro - doesnt work when csv file is larger then 15MB

Tags: vba, excel

I am having issues with the below code.

The macro is supposed to replace "," with "-" and apply two filters. Filter all values at "0" and filter all values "Main" and delete all rows with the combination "0" and "Main".

It works perfectly, except when my csv file is larger then 15 MB. In such cases, the code just "loops out" so to speak. It doesn't throw an error or anything, it simply stops the process and I am able to continue by hand. No errors, no crashes, no freezes, nothing, as if it didn't even run?

The macro is recorded, it seemed like an easier solution, maybe that's the potential issue.

```
Sub Find_and_replace_and_filter_all()

' ALL_FIND_REPLACE_FILTER_DELTE Macro for all.csv

    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet

    Set wkb = Excel.Workbooks.Open("G:\Users\Documents\all.csv")
    Set wks = wkb.Worksheets("all")

    wks.Cells.Replace What:=",", Replacement:="-", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
        :=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:= _
        False
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$5903").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:="0"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$5903").AutoFilter field:=9, Criteria1:="Main"
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.AutoFilter

    wkb.Close saveChanges:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Your range is limited to 5903 lines. Perhaps the 15 MB-csv-file has more lines?

Comment: It's not causing your issue, but the range `"$A$1:$AC$5903"` seems quite specific, yet your file sizes are variable by the sounds of things. Should you not make this more dynamic or are all your files 5903 or fewer rows?

Comment: Yes, you are right, spot on, Thank you. The recording was the problem, I didn't think about it. The file I recorded the macro for the first time had that many lines.